# How can I get support on Google's Progressive Web Apps?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, outsourcing

The official Google's Progressive Web Apps page, https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/ links to Stack Overflow to "Get support". But when I tried to ask support about Progressive Web Apps, my question was put on hold. And it will be closed and deleted, as I suppose. The technique is new and there is not so much information about it, so dummy questions are normal. Searching on Google does not get me the required information. No other support options are mentioned on the Progressive Web Apps page except Stack Overflow. What to do now?

Comment: Be sure to read the paragraph starting with *"If the referring company did not give you clear guidance [...]"*

Comment: To be specific to your question: It is broad (closure reason), mainly the question is "Can I do X with Y": Which only Y's support can really answer. Even if it works, it may be a not desired feature and if it is not documented it may vanish without advice. If the feature is documented, then try yourself, show your attempt and ask why your attempt doesn't work as expected.

Comment: And for what it worth, your question seems not so related to PWA and more about using GMap offline.

Comment: @Stijn Thank you for the link. I wrote a question to the SO team.

Comment: @Tensibai I will try to remake my question, many thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[Your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094123/is-it-possible-to-create-google-maps-web-page-using-progressive-web-app-for-offl) wasn't put on hold because it is off-topic, but because it is too broad:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.

A good answer to this question wouldn't be just 'yes' or 'no'. If 'yes', it would require a (potentially very long) code sample. 'No' can basically only be confirmed by the framework's authors.

So, please try it yourself, and if you're stuck with a specific problem, that could be a good question for Stack Overflow.